# adobe illustrator Script for textframe having enter key

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, text-wrap

thanks in advance for any assistance regarding this issue

i am not scripting guy
i copied this script from somewhere i don't remember

var document = app.activeDocument;
var TextFrame = activeDocument.selection;
TextFrames = activeDocument.selection;
TextFrame.contents = "Hello friends, how are you.";

problem is
i need this textframe to be two line and text cursor should not be at start but be at end so that i can start tying from the end

any help appreciated

Comment: You need to check "insertion point" in the scripting documentation.

Comment: Try putting \n in the text, where the new line should begin.

Comment: Thanks Kris Van Bael
 i am happy   \n worked for new line
my second issue still same :-  about cursor not shifting at end of line/ statement .